# SharePoint 2007 - MP4 Issue

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2007

In one of our SharePoint 2007 web-application, when we click on .MP4 file we are getting some illegal characters page.

But in another web-application it is opening fine in client media player. This is what is we are looking out for, can someone help how to get this issue resolved.

Thanks,

Praveen

Comment: both web application in the same farm? having the same configuration?

Comment: Yes they are in the same farm with same configuration